# How to make a page where two content types are combined

Tags: views

It should be a portfolio website. I'm going to place there information about projects I was engaged in and products I designed. The relationships between project and product nodes are those:

```
--Project 1
----Product 1
----Product 2
----Product 3
--Project 2
----Product 4
----Product 5
----Product 6
etc.
```

My question. How to create a page where placed all project articles and under each project article there should be related product article teasers. Like on image.
[image: Page template]

Answer (score 0):

In views you can "Group By" the parent nodes. So if you were using entity references to do the relationship, you would have it as a field in views and group by it.

Are they different content types? How are you relating the children to the parent?

If the default Group By isn't enough, there's a module called Views Field View which can put a view inside a view but that could be a bit unnecessary.

Answer (score -2):

a quick solution could be writing a very simple code. in your .module code in a page call back
take all the data that you want and then group them into an array first that is something like this

```
$query = "SELECT
nid,
title,
field_data_first_field_table.first_field_table AS first_filed_table,
field_data_second_filed_table.first_filed_table AS second_filed_table
FROM
node LEFT JOIN first_field_table
ON
field_data_first_field_table.entity_id = node.nid
LEFT JOIN field_data_second_filed_table
ON
field_data_second_filed_table.entity_id = node.nid
 WHERE node.type IN(:type);
 $result = db_query($query, (':type' =>array('type1','type2'));
  while ( $data = $result->fetchObject () ) {
  $portfolio_array[$data -> title][$data ->first_filed_table][second_filed_table] = $data ->nid;
 }
```

in the $portfolio_array you will have that values grouped .you can push this to a theme function (very best) or return that formatted output in the call back function itself.

second method is views module use rlationships to add the fields and then make your theme changes in the correpsonding views

Comment: Never mind, but I down-voted this answer for the lack of obeying Drupal coding standards/best practices and the error-prone query (missing entity type/bundle conditions on the fields and so on).

Comment: I'd like to avoid codding if it's possible. So the second method. I understand how to do it for one project article per page. But how to do it for multiple project articles with several product articles for each?